# Как редактировать иконку стороннего приложения?

Tags: c#, файлы

Есть приложение, которое не содержит иконку, то есть простой exe-шник. При определенных действиях он копируется на флешку программно, но продолжает висеть без иконки.

**Вопрос**: как сделать, чтобы после копирования файл приобрел иконку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть программа [resourcehacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) с помощью него можно поменять ресурс, который отвечает за иконку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это я знаю, но нужно сделать замену иконки именно из самого приложения, программно

Comment: У WinApi есть функции для этого https://stackoverflow.com/a/2760204/4244707

Comment: мне нужно на C# реализовать

Comment: @МишаКуликовский так-то WinApi доступен в C# через P/Invoke